# Logging using Log4j.xml in Glassfish

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j, glassfish-3

I was using **WAS** as my application server for deploying ear project.Presently changed to **Glassfish**. I am using log4j.xml file for logging. Logging is not working in Glassfish.

Is there any dependency in using log4j.xml with glassfish.

Any suggestions/pointers is appreciated

Comment: have you packaged the log4j.xml file in a jar?

Comment: How was your log4j jar declared?  Was it included in each EAR, or shared between EARs using a shared library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your log4j library is included within your EAR file, then check your app server's JVM properties to ensure the log4j.configuration property is set:

1. Login to the Glassfish Admin Console (http://[hostname]:4848/)
2. For your server, navigate to Configuration > JVM Settings > JVM Options
3. If an entry for -Dlog4j.configuration exists, verify that it contains the location of your log4j.xml file
4. If an entry *do not exist* for -Dlog4j.configuration, create one.  It must follow the following template: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/your/log4j.xml

Comment: I have multiple EAR modules deployed, for example take ear1, ear2 and ear3. The log4j.xml file is present in ear1. The log entries from the classes in ear2 is the ones causing issue.   he log entries from the classes in ear2 were appearing while using WAS. The issue happens when using glassfish. Also if i had a log4j.xml file to ear2. The logs are appearing. Any explanation on the working will be very useful