# EJB SLF4J with log4j - No appenders could be found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to use SLF4J with log4j in a Bean inside a EJB, I have already tried to place the log4j.properties file in quite a few places but I keep getting this error in the Glassfish Server console:

```
Grave:   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (uy.ort.enviosya.cadets.services.CadetsBean).
Grave:   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Grave:   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
```

This is my properties file:

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1,Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:/Users/Log4jWebDemo.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

The questions related to this problem say I should place it in the classpath but honestly I don't know what they mean by that (totally new to EJB).

This is what I'm doing in the bean:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean implements SomeBeanRemote {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeBean.class);

    @Override
    public someMethod() {
        LOGGER.info("Prueba");
        ...
    }

   ...
}
```

Plus, should I be placing the file inside the EJB? What if I want to modify the destination of the `Appender2` then?

I'm using Netbeans 8.2.

### **Update 1**

I have placed it inside the `META-INF` folder of my ejb, and from what I can see it is present in that same folder in the `Cadets-ejb.jar` that I'm deploying inside `.ear`.

But I'm still getting the same error.

Partial folder structure:

```
Some
    build
    Some-ejb
        build
        dist
        nbproject
        src
            conf
                META-INF
            java
        test
    dist
    lib
    nbproject
    src
```

### **Update 2**

I managed to get it working but by placing the properties file by hand in the correct place in the build folder, which means I need to do this every time I do a clean-build.

I tried placing it in the src folder but when I build it doesn't get copied, only what is inside `src/conf`gets copied and that is the wrong location for this file.

Why is the file in `src` being ignored on build?

This is my structure now:

```
Some
    /build
    /Some-ejb
        /build
        /dist
        /nbproject
        /src
            /conf
                /META-INF
                   MANIFEST.MF
            /java
           /log4j.properties
        /test
    /dist
    /lib
       /log4j.jar
    /nbproject
    /src
```

I now that the file, once the jar is created needs no be at the same level that `META-INF`and my class packages.

### **Solution**

I solved it by placing it here

```
Some
    /build
    /Some-ejb
        /build
        /dist
        /nbproject
        /src
            /conf
                /META-INF
                   MANIFEST.MF
            /java
                log4j.properties
        /test
    /dist
    /lib
       /log4j.jar
    /nbproject
    /src
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673670/logging-using-log4j-xml-in-glassfish or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j

Comment: @CarlosLaspina Thanks, I have read those and tried but I keep getting the error. I have updated the question explaining where it is now.

Comment: What is your folder structure for your project? What is the version of you server?

Comment: @CarlosLaspina just included a partial folder structure

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/where-should-i-put-the-log4j-properties-file https://sites.google.com/site/bugsarewelcome/home/configure-log4j-for-use-in-glassfish-3-1 or http://javaworkbench.blogspot.com/2011/07/configure-log4j-with-glassfish.html

Answer (score 0):

After I googled a lot, i think i found a solution for this:

**FOR A GLOBAL CONFIGURATION**

If your log4j library is included within your EAR file, then check your app server's JVM properties to ensure the log4j.configuration property is set:

1. Login to the Glassfish Admin Console (http://[hostname]:4848/)
2. Click on 'Server(Admin Server)'-> Click on 'server-config' Configuration -> JVM Settings -> JVM Options. (depends of your server version, but the important is JVM Settings > JVM Options)
3. If an entry for `-Dlog4j.configuration` exists, verify that it contains the location of your log4j.properties file
4. If an entry *do not exist* for `-Dlog4j.configuration`, create one.  It must follow the following template: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/your/log4j.properties`
5. Restart the GlassFish.
6. Deploy sample app and check if the Log4J statements are now available.

In case your project doesn't contain log4j library

1. Copy log4j.jar inside the GLASSFISH_HOME/lib.

**FOR A PROJECT**

For instance, you can have the following structure:

```
Some
    /build
    /Some-ejb
        /build
        /dist
        /nbproject
        /src
            /conf
                /META-INF
                   MANIFEST.MF
            /java
        /test
    /dist
    /lib
       /log4j.jar
    /nbproject
    /src
       /log4j.properties
```

In order to include the log4j-files into your classpath, you have to put the following into the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` on your EJB Project:

```
Class-Path: src lib/log4j.jar
```

Yes: it’s relative to the EAR, not to the EJB Project.

Do not put the `log4j.properties` itself in the classpath, only the directory that contains that file.

Comment: In this case every ear that I deploy to the server will be using the same properties, right? I'm deploying more than one and I want them to be independent.

Comment: I updated my answer, please try this and give me your feedback.

Comment: I tried it and have updated the question, by placing it in the `src` folder it doesn't get copy to the `build` folder on  build